# How can I get Firebase to display the same id in three separate areas of the database?

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase

I have an app that uses firebase-functions that is used by both Android & iOS.

With the below **Android** recordToFirebase() method:

- it adds a 'history' node
- it adds a 'history' node to both Users/Drivers & Users/Riders
- it sets the id to true in both Users/Drivers & Users/Riders

```
    DatabaseReference riderRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Riders").child(riderId).child("history");

    DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Drivers").child(driverId).child("history");

    final DatabaseReference historyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("history");

    requestId = historyRef.push().getKey(); // same key for all 3 refs
    driverRef.child(requestId).setValue(true);
    riderRef.child(requestId).setValue(true);
```

When running the above code in Android, it should do this in the db, which it
does, it also assigns the sign id for all 3 (history/id, Users/Drivers/history/id, Users/Riders/history/id):

```json
- Users
  - Drivers
    - history
      - Ljdfuhkd8_kdnjd : true

  - Riders
    - history
      - Ljdfuhkd8_kdnjd : true

- history
  - Ljdfuhkd8_kdnjd
    - email: me@me.com
```

In **iOS**, same method (same as Android, just in Swift):

```
let historyRef = ref.child("history")
let riderRef = ref.child("Users/Riders").child(riderID).child("history")
let driverRef  = ref.child("Users/Drivers").child(driverID).child("history")

driverRef.childByAutoId().setValue(true)        
riderRef.childByAutoId().setValue(true)
```

When the above Swift method is run, it does not do what the Android code does,
it assigns a different id for all three.

How I can rewrite this code to work like it does in the Android code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for IOS:

```
let historyRef = ref.child("history")
let riderRef = ref.child("Users/Riders").child(riderID).child("history")
let driverRef  = ref.child("Users/Drivers").child(driverID).child("history")

let key = historyRef.childByAutoId().key
historyRef.child(key).setValue(true) 
riderRef.child(key).setValue(true) 
driverRef.child(key).setValue(true)
```

Comment: I have been working on this for 3 days and assumed this is what was causing my problem. Perfection at its best